# How to sed search and replace without changing ownership

Tags: unix, sed, replace

I found this command line search and replace example:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/find/replace/g'
```

It worked fine except it changed the date and file ownership on EVERY file it searched through, even those that did not contain the search text.

What's a better solution to this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `-c` option (if you are on Linux) ought to cause sed to preserve ownership.  As you are using the command, it is in fact rewriting every file, even though it is not making changes to the files that do not contain `find`.

Comment: ah just noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: What versions of `sed` have `-c`? My GNU `sed` 4.2.1 doesn't.

Comment: I was working from the man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed -- the man page for sed on a CentOS 4 install I use shows `-c` as an option and `sed --version` reports `GNU sed version 4.1.2`; ditto for a CentOS 5 install where `sed --version` reports `GNU sed version 4.1.5`; MacOSX does not have the `-c` option, which is why I specified Linux.

Comment: For googlers: it seems that `-c` is indeed not in GNU sed, it's a patch added by RedHat (added most recently here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=566455, changelog here: http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.2.1511/x86_64/Packages/sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64.html).  Other distros may have pulled it in too, but I don't have it in Arch, and it's not in GNU's manpage: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to fix that would be to only execute sed on the files if the contain the text by using grep first:

```
find . -type f | while read file; do
    grep -q find $file && sed -i 's/find/replace/g' $file
done
```

This does require reading each file twice (in the worst case), so it might be a little slower.  Hopefully, though, your OS should keep the file in its disk cache, so you shouldn't see much of a slowdown, since this process is definitely I/O-bound, not CPU-bound.

Comment: As per Isaac's answer, I'd have to add -c to your solution to prevent the change in ownership, right?

Comment: don't have to use `grep+sed`. sed `'/find/s/find/replace/g'`

Comment: The `grep` was to avoid applying sed at all to files that don't need to be changed and thus avoid changing their modification time.

Answer (score 2):

Some distro's versions of `sed` (namely, RedHat and family) have added a `-c` option that accomplishes this, in which case see @Isaac's answer.

But for those with an unpatched GNU sed, the easiest way I've found is to simply substitute with perl, which rewrites files similar to `sed -c` when available.  The following commands are basically equivalent:

```
sed -ci 's/find/replace/'
perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/'
```

Just don't get too excited and do `perl -pie`; like with `sed -ie`, instead of interpreting as another option, it will use `e` as an argument to `-i`, and use it as a suffix to backup the original file.  See `perldoc perlrun` for more details there.

Perl's regex parsing is a little different from sed (better, imo) for more complicated things: generally speaking, use less backslashes.

Comment: This answer is now a couple years old, but I've given it a try, and unfortunately also the perl command changed the ownership of the file I'm working on, at least on perl 5, version 38